# Overloading Input Operator for std::vector C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload `operator>>` for a `std::vector<T>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, std::vector<T>& v)
{
    T elem;
    while(in >> elem)
    {
        v.push_back(elem);
    }
    return in;
}
```

The thing I don't know is how to break the input loop when a user enter nothing(just hit 'enter'). I know the solution for `std::string` using `getline()` but it isn't sufficient for this case.

Comment: should already work as expected unless `T` is string, does it not?

Comment: No, it doesn't. For example it doesn't work for ```std::vector<int>```. The only way to break the loop is to send end-of-file.